# How to integrate Thunderbird with SpamAssassin running on the server?

Tags: thunderbird, spamassassin

I'm trying to integrate SpamAssassin running on a server with Thunderbird. Basically I need to be able to select several emails in Thunderbird and send them back to SpamAssassin for training, either as spam or ham.

I tried several approaches:

1. Tried "Report Spam" plugin, which is able to send message back to server either as an email attachment or via HTTP post. However, the plugin is rather buggy... Does not support sending several messages at once, "report as ham" is not working at all, etc.
2. Wanted to make a custom button that will copy selected messages to a separate IMAP folder (I could create "LearnAsSpam" and "LearnAsHam" folders in IMAP that will get processed automatically on server), but don't even know how to approach this in Thunderbird, don't want to learn Thunderbird extention authoring...

Server-side, I'm prepared to do some custom programming or integration needed (can receive a message via HTTP / SMTP / whatever), my stumbling block is Thunderbird...

So, how can I send emails from Thunderbird back to SpamAssassin running on email server for Bayesian training, with as few keystrokes as possible?

Comment: Does this plugin still work with a modern thunderbird? [http://sourceforge.net/projects/soc2006spamd/]

Comment: My email provider (Tuffmail) provides folders called "spam" and "ham" for this purpose. I suppose you could do the same thing with a [Thunderbird add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), but if anybody has written one, they haven't bothered to upload it

Comment: @Hennes: Says "not compatible" when trying to install. I haven't tried to force it and see if it works or not...

Comment: Possibility: run a server side process to process any messages that are saved to the ham/spam folders....

Comment: @Yedric: Yeah, I know (and this is probably the way to go if I don't receive a better answer). However, I would like to do it with one mouseclick/keyboard shortcut. Doing Message|MoveTo|Recent|Spam or Message|CopyTo|Recent|Ham each time I want to train SpamAssassin is tiresome. Pity I cannot assign a shortcut or make a toolbar button for these two actions easily.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to configure Thunderbird's Junk button behavior to fit your needs. Two steps are required:

1. Go to `Tools | Options | Security | Junk` (or on OSX, `Preferences | Security`) and tick `When I mark messages as junk:` and `Move them to the account's "Junk" folder`
2. Go to `Tools | Account Settings...`, locate your mail account and proceed to `Junk Settings` for that account. Chose `Move new messages to Other:` and select the desired IMAP folder.

Reference: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages

Comment: For anyone else thinking this doesn't work, read the answer more carefully that I did the first time. You have to change an option in Settings/Preferences as well as in the Account Settings. Works perfectly then.